# Tc3_EventLogger library error in BeckHoff TwinCat3

Tags: plc, twincat

When i'm trying to compile a program in TwinCat 3 using the library Tc3_EventLogger. I'm using TwinCat3 Build 4018.58.

I receive the following errors (Please take a look at the image below):
[**TC3 Compile Error Picture**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mSAK.png)

These are the errors I received as plain text :

- 'Verbose' is no component of 'TCEVENTSEVERITY' [tc3_eventlogger, 3.1.28.0
  (beckhoff automation gmbh)].
- Cannot convert type 'Unknown type: 'TcEventSeverity.Verbose'' to type
  'TCEVENTSEVERITY' [tc3_eventlogger, 3.1.28.0 (beckhoff automation gmbh)].
- Initialisation of constant variable 'EMPTY_SEVERITY' not constant [tc3_eventlogger, 3.1.28.0 (beckhoff automation gmbh)].

I already tried to delete and add the library again but that didn't solve the problem.
How can I solve it?
Thanks

Comment: Hi עומר דגן, welcome to StackOverflow! What version of Tc3 were you using? Do you have a code-snippet of the program in where you are using the Tc3_EventLogger? I just tried with TwinCAT 4024.22 and it all worked fine.

Comment: Hi עומר דגן, welcome to StackOverflow! Your image doesn't show currently, You should add the ! before the [] to show it. See for more info the [markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Also can you post the exact error in plain text, such that other people searching for the same thing can easily find it? You can find more tips on how to frame your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hey , I'm using TwinCat build 4018.58 .

Comment: Ok added errors plain text , unfortunately I am not able to use ! to show the picture.